# Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found

Tags: r, statistics

I am new to R. Here is my code:

```
s= rolldie(2, makespace = TRUE)
s = addrv(s, FUN=sum, name="U")
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

How to solve it? Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am assuming `rolldie` and `addrv` functions are from `prob` package? You should include all the non-base packages in the post. This works for me without any error though. Try this in fresh session, restart R and run the code again.

Comment: @RonakShah, Yes, I used prob package. I restarted R but no luck! I am getting the same error!